# Show custom action in ribbon for only one list

Tags: list, ribbon, custom-actions

Does anyone knows how to show a custom action in the ribbon for only one list?
At this moment I've got multiple custom lists, but my button is added on all of them. I only want to show it on one particular list...

(I found [a simular question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18274/in-sharepoint-how-to-display-custom-ribbon-button-to-particular-lists-only/27800#27800), but there isn't a good solution for it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can associate your custom action to a specific list by using the `RegistrationId` property.

Example:

```
<CustomAction ControlAssembly="MagicalProject.Actions" 
                ControlClass="MagicalProject.Actions" 
                ControlSrc="/_layouts/MagicalSite/MagicalPage.aspx" 
                Description="This is my custom action which does magical stuff" 
                GroupId="MyMagicalActions" 
                Id="f5bcd75e-23b9-4623-9a82-41cc7ceb10a6" 
                RegistrationId="MyMagicalList" // Or whatever other identifier you have for your lists
                RegistrationType="List" 
                RequireSiteAdministrator="false" 
                Rights="AddListItems" 
                Sequence="1" 
                ShowInReadOnlyContentTypes="false" 
                ShowInSealedContentTypes="false" 
                Title="MyCustomAction">
```

UPDATE: It also applies for ContentTypes. So if you associate it with a contenttype, then all lists inheriting that specific contenttype will also get this custom action. In case you wanted to know how to put it on more than 1 list.

All it takes is changing `RegistrationType` from `List` to `ContentType`

Comment: I've used as RegistrationId the Id from the list and than it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't the registration id used to specifiy a list ServerTemplate id? You can associate the custom action to a specific template (es: generic list, document libray, image library ecc), but I don't think you can use the registration id to specify a string name of a list.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms460194.aspx) you can. I think you might be thinking about RegistrationType.

Comment: @Dandroid. From my experience, the registration id is used to specify a list template id (you must also set the parameter RegistrationType to "List"). That way you can for associate your action with every list of a set template - be it Survey (102), GenericList (100), PictureLibrary (109) ecc ecc. I am not aware if you could also use a list name/url/other in place of the template id - I will test this when I get some time, for now this is a nice thing to know (that would open new way to implement things).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: Have you got the chance of testing this? I'm currently in a similar situation (more external content types and want to add the ribbon extras just for one of them) and used the list name for the `RegistrationId` and it does not work. I don't have an ID for the list as It's created at the same type with the action. @Dandroid: If I have no list ID how can this be done?

Comment: @JohnDoDo: sorry, haven't still got the time to test this theory. [THIS blog](http://blog.alexboev.com/2011/12/registrationtype-registrationid-in.html) seems to confirm the opposite (cit: ""Despite the “List” name you can’t use this type of registration with list unique identifier, title, URL or any other list property. RegistrationId for the “List” RegistrationType must correspond to the base list template identifier of the list where customization should appear). Anyway, I'm more prone to try a programmatic approach to the problem - create the action in a feature event receiver.

Comment: @JohnDoDo: One more thing. I'm not sure I fully understood your situation, but if you need to add your custom action to a specific **Content Type** you may try to change the registration type to ContentType and set the RegistrationID to the id of your CT.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: I also thought of content types (i.e. create a "marker" one and use that) but I'm using an external list so there is no content type :(. I turned to a minimal configuration with some specific code for the ribbon item but [haven't been able to make it work yet](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28475/adding-custom-button-to-ribbon-button-doesnt-get-displayed).

Comment: @JohnDoDo You always have the List ID. When you go to a list, check the URL, it should contain a parameter called "lid" or "listid". Unless you have URL changing apps on your server, this id is always available via the URL.

Comment: It's just like magic, baby!

Answer (score 6):

I've made some research on the subject of RegistrationId and RegistrationType according to declarative Ribbon customization. All my findings can be found here:

[RegistrationType & RegistrationId in SharePoint 2010 declarative Ribbon customizations](http://blog.alexboev.com/2011/12/registrationtype-registrationid-in.html)

As a short summary: You can use all four registration types to target some content for Ribbon customization.

And concerning your question: There's no direct option to specify single list instance by means of registrationid. But there's a workaround; you can create an unique content type for your specific list and use RegistrationType = ContentType to target it.

Another way you can go is the programmatic Ribbon customization.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **EnabledScript** parameter in [CommandUIHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458385.aspx), where you can put javascript code and check if specific page/list/view is loaded.

Example:

```
<CommandUIHandler 
  Command="Ribbon.ListItem.CustomGroup.Controls.BtnSayHello.Command"
  CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello');"
  EnabledScript="javascript:
    function isEnable(){
      if(location.href.indexOf('AllItems.aspx') > 0){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    isEnable();"
/>
```

Comment: beautiful hack !

Comment: downvoted: WRONG answer - it still be in **all** lists (in disabled state)

Comment: Why in all lists? You can easily specify to which list you register the action (see other posts)(sorry, I didn't mention this). But you cannot assign action to specify view of list. So my post gives you solution how to specify on which view/page will be the action visible.