# Adding custom button to ribbon - Button doesn't get displayed

Tags: list, ribbon, custom-actions, personalization

I'm trying to add a custom button to a SP2010 ribbon in the `DisplayFormToolbar` for a list item. The list is external, although I don't think that matters but still...

This is my custom action definition:

```
  <CustomAction Id="{0116B081-B13E-4A4B-8F8D-EF7AC1E43BFD}"
                Location="DisplayFormToolbar"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="600"
                Sequence="1"
                ControlAssembly="myAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...."
                ControlClass="myNamespace.MyRibbonButton" />
```

`myNamespace.MyRibbonButton` class extends `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button` and has some basic code inside `OnInit`.

When I access the display form of an item in the external list, in debug I can see that `OnInit` is executed, there is no exception in the logs... but the button does not show in the form!

I have specified my assembly with `SafeControl` so that's not the cause.

Even if I add this to my custom action is still does not display:

```
<CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 ribbon doesn't have anything in common with 2007's `DisplayFormToolBar`.

The custom action *Location* attribute should be set to "CommandUI.Ribbon" for adding something to ribbon.

Then, you should provide special XML for button. Since SP2010 ribbon is a client-side thing, no C# code is involved here.

You can find a simple example of adding a button to ribbon here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfrost/archive/2009/11/06/adding-custom-button-to-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon.aspx

P.S. Also, you can consider using [SharePoint 2010 Fluent Ribbon API](http://spribbon.codeplex.com) opensource project to work with ribbon in a simplified way. A quick how-to start can be found [at project's documentation site](http://markeev.com/sharepoint/ribbon/?topic=html/ribbonCustomAction.htm). It is my project actually, and I cannot resist mentioning that it is a rather popular project and we use it in real-world projects at work intensively.

Comment: Are you saying that I can't use the `ControlAssembly`/`ControlClass` attributes to define my own control to show in the ribbon? Also, I've set the location to "CommandUI.Ribbon" and the button is still not displayed and now my code isn't executed anymore!

Comment: That's right, ribbon controls could be defined using **XML** only, and actions for them are specified as JavaScript code.

Comment: So what are the `ControlAssembly` and `ControlClass` attributes used for then?

Comment: They may be used for some other customizations, which are performed through CustomActions. But not for ribbon customizations.

Comment: Please consider the following MSDN article, which describes possibilities of Ribbon customizations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539395.aspx

Comment: Thanks omlin! I'll check it out as well as your project on codeplex. The thing is I'm trying to set the button just for one particular list (same issue as described here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/show-custom-action-in-ribbon-for-only-one-list/) and need to filter it through code. I found something similar here: http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/how_to_add_a_custom_action_to.html and thought to use it for the ribbon. But off course it does not work...

Comment: If you need merely to apply filtering, the simplest way would be to create several pre-filtered views and just to switch between them when the ribbon button is pressed. By eye, this will be very similar to the described postback approach.