# How to add CustomAction button in Ribbon of DocumentLibrary in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, office-365, custom-action

How can I add a CustomAction button in Ribbon of Document Library in SharePoint Online (Office-365) for Sandbox solution without any code ?

I have created team-site in SharePoint Online. And having Document Library in that. Now I want to add a CustomAction button in Ribbon sothat I can take action for multiple documents simultaneously.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Would you like your action to be added in all Document Libraries or only one particular Document Library?

Comment: Currently, I want to add action button in one particular Document Library.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/show-custom-action-in-ribbon-for-only-one-list