# How to add buttons on CommandBar - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom, command-set

How do I add custom buttons(CommandBarItems) on CommandBar in Modern View of SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

Create a SharePoint Framework Extention.

More info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the below given links for help:.

[Add a button to Command Bar of a SharePoint online](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Add-a-button-to-Command-Bar-of-a-SharePoint-online-Library-All/td-p/66761)

[Add CustomAction button in Ribbon of DocumentLibrary in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60804/how-to-add-customaction-button-in-ribbon-of-documentlibrary-in-sharepoint-online)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add buttons in red part:
[image]

Refer to: [Build your first ListView Command Set Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)