# Custom ribbon button in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, ribbon, custom-actions

I need to create custom ribbon for document library. I tried creating custom ribbon button with registration id as 101, but it shows ribbon in all document library.

I also tried using content type intead of registration id, ribbon was shown only to document library using that content type.

But i had 2 document library with same content type and i need custom ribbon button in only one document library.

How to create this?

Comment: Did you went through this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/show-custom-action-in-ribbon-for-only-one-list

Comment: I tried this. Ribbon was not created.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by using EnabledScript property in Custom Action.

I verified whether current list is my custom list and enabled the button. For the rest of the lists the ribbon button will be shown but disabled.

I referred [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/af1df2f0-34fc-4259-ab5c-3fbe1df47333).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to scope a Custom Action more than on a content type I am afraid. Is javascript in a content editor webpart on the page that displays the one list an alternative?

See this link for all information regarding different registration types for Custom Actions http://blog.alexboev.com/2011/12/registrationtype-registrationid-in.html

Comment: So there is no solution for this scenario right??

Comment: Not just using a Custom Action

Comment: Then how can i proceed? I need a button in document library. On clicking that button, i need to navigate to another page.

Comment: What was the custom action supposed to do? You could write some javascript, placed in a content editor webpart on the display page, that inserts a button to the ribbon with an onclick event calling another javascript function that does what your custom action was supposed to do :)

Comment: I need the button in ribbon. So only i choose custom actions.

Comment: And custom action will not be narrow enough in scope for you... You could add a button in the ribbon with javascript as I said. Otherwise you will have the button in all lists using your content type and might have to write some code in the custom action that aborts the action if called from the incorrect list. That's about all the options you have.

Comment: Do i need to write javascript code in DisplayForm.aspx using SharePoint designer? I could not find any sample for creating ribbon other than custom action.