# Custom Action for a specific view?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, custom

I have a list, where I wish to display a Custom Action button. This is easy enough to do in SPD, but the catch is, I only want to display this Custom Action button for a specific view, not the default "All Items" view.

I am seeing no obvious way to achieve this. Even going deep into the Visual Studio 2010 end with custom Ribbon buttons I am only finding a way to associate them with a list and not a specific view witin that list.

Is there a way to bind a Custom Action button to a specific view, and not just the list as a whole?

This is for SP2010 Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution is possible in SPD. 
But in xml definition you can use **EnabledScript** parameter in [CommandUIHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458385.aspx), where you can put javascript code and check if specific page/list/view is loaded.

[link to similar answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/130987/14566)

Example:

```
<CommandUIHandler 
  Command="Ribbon.ListItem.CustomGroup.Controls.BtnSayHello.Command"
  CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello');"
  EnabledScript="javascript:
    function isEnable(){
      if(location.href.indexOf('AllItems.aspx') > 0){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    isEnable();"
/>
```