# How to add a custom action to the list ribbon?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog, custom-actions

How to add a custom action to the list ribbon?

The custom action should open a sitepage in modal popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction Id="9b3d1a59-78ca-45da-aa2c-4964e3f68c58.AppHost-RCA"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="100"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    Sequence="10001"
    Title="Invoke &apos;AppHost_RCA&apos; action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
    <!--
    Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
    that you want to enable for the custom action.
    -->
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
    <Button Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.AppHost-RCAButton"
    Alt="Request App"
    Sequence="100"
    Command="Invoke_AppHost-RCAButtonRequest"
    LabelText="Request App"
    TemplateAlias="o1"
    Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
    Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_AppHost-RCAButtonRequest"
    CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx"/>
    </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
    </CustomAction>
    </Elements>
```

- See more at: http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2013.html#sthash.Ic1fEx3A.dpuf

Comment: a video also available: http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-ribbon-custom-action-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Answer (score 1):

You can associate your custom action to a specific list by using the RegistrationId property.

Check this post, already have answer.

[Show custom action in ribbon for only one list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/show-custom-action-in-ribbon-for-only-one-list)