# JS File in custom ribbon button loads on all pages

Tags: 2013, ribbon, xml, elements-xml

We have a custom ribbon button and we have added code to refer JS file in it. The ribbon button is bound to content type.

```
<CustomAction
Id="MyProject.RibbonButton"
Location="ScriptLink" 
ScriptSrc ="~sitecollection/Style Library/JS/MyProjectRibbonButton.js"/>
```

But `MyProjectRibbonButton.js` file is loaded on all the pages - site settings, home page - where the ribbon button is not event visible.

What is the cause of this issue?

**Edit 1:**

From Danny's comment below it seems that `Location="ScriptLink"` makes it load on all the pages. Any way I can make it load on only those pages where ribbon button is present?

Comment: It is not an issue, since SP2010 the CustomAction type **ScriptLink** is intended to load on all pages. Very powerful, alas does not execute on Microsofts Modern Experiences

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman: Any way I can make it to load on only those pages where ribbon button gets loaded?

Comment: [Show custom action in ribbon for only one list](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/show-custom-action-in-ribbon-for-only-one-list)  - check this link. You need to modify accordingly.

Comment: @GautamSheth: I want to load the JS file where the ribbon button is present. As of now it loads across all the pages. Your link is for loading ribbon button and not JS file.

Comment: @Naveen, no, a **ScriptLink** loads on all pages --period--  Have you read the Microsoft documentation about CustomActions?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman: Okay. I get it. ScriptLink loads JS across all pages. But is there a way to load the JS only when the associated ribbon button is loaded for a page?

Comment: I don't have time now to open Google search for the MSDN Manual about CustomActions, copy paste the text and answer your question. I will try tonight