# Add CustomAction to only one folder in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, custom-actions

I have the following PowerShell script for creating custom action on a list in a document library.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://[my_tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[my_page]"
Add-PnPCustomAction -Name 'Test 1' -Title 'Test 1' -Description 'Test 1' -Group 'SiteActions' -RegistrationType 'List' -RegistrationId '101' -Location 'EditControlBlock' -Sequence 3010 -Url 'https://www.google.com'
```

This works fine and adds a custom action to every library on the SharePoint.

[image]

My question now is: How can I add the action only to a specific folder (folder 1) in a specific list (list 2)? The other items should not have this custom action!

```
- list 1
  - folder
    - file 1
    - file 2
- list 2
  - folder 1 <- only this one should have a custom action
    - file 1
    - file 2
  - folder 2
    - file 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Microsoft documentation, [CustomAction Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/customaction-element):

Possible values `RegistrationType` includes:

- None
- List
- ContentType
- ProgId
- FileType

So, you cannot directly provide folder name or URL/path and add custom action to only that one folder.

You can try below suggestions:

**A. Using custom content type**:

1. Create a custom content type inheriting the default Folder content type
2. Add custom content type to library
3. Create a folder using the custom content type
4. Add custom action to this particular content type by using `RegistrationType` = `ContentType`.

**A. Using custom action to specific list** (Not tested):

1. As per [the thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/show-custom-action-in-ribbon-for-only-one-list), you can show custom action in for only one list by using GUID/Name of list in `RegistrationId`.
2. Then add some logic in `EnabledScript` function to check if the specific folder is selected or not.
3. As per this documentation, you can get selected `ItemId` with menu item custom actions: [Create custom actions to deploy with SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-custom-actions-to-deploy-with-sharepoint-add-ins)

Comment: thanks, the first suggestion works and is 'good enough' for us, so i didn't test the second one